# Backward compatiblity in reading json of different types in gson object reader

Tags: json, gson

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "name": "v19",
  "timestamp" : 1475733360000,
  "type": "long",
  "value": 123
}
```

And the new JSON format is that the above goes inside `metrics` array and `meta_data` is added:

```
{
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "v19",
      "timestamp" : 1475733360000,
      "type": "long",
      "value": 123
    }
  ],
  "meta_data": {
    "timestamp" : 1474367139000,
    "count": {
      "app1" : 120
    }
  }
}
```

Is using `try-catch` is the only way to handle both types of JSON? Or is there a better way?

Right now my code looks like below:

```
switch (reader.peek())
{
    case BEGIN_OBJECT:
        try
        {
            MetaDataMetric metaMetric = parseMetaMetric(reader);
        }
        catch 
        {
            NewMetric metric = parseMetric(reader);
        }
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use **"Since"** and **"Until"** annotations for this use case. When you create the Gson object, the version can be set. The API will serialize or de-serialize based on the annotation **`@Since`** and **`@Until`** annotations and version number.

**Big advantage of using this approach:-**

The Gson version can be maintained in application property file. The code can be executed with 1.0 or 1.1 version based on the requirement if you have dependency e.g. any other interface, web services etc.

This is the **standard best practice** to support multiple versions of JSON.

```
Gson gsonv10 = new GsonBuilder().setVersion(1.0).create();
```

> @Since - An annotation that indicates the version number since a
>   member or a type has been present.
>
> @Until - An annotation that indicates the version number until a member or a
>   type should be present.

**JSON to Object:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String version10Json = "{\"name\": \"v19\",\"timestamp\" : 1475733360000,\"type\": \"long\",\"value\": 123}";
        String version11Json = "{\"metrics\":[{\"name\":\"v19\",\"timestamp\":1475733360000,\"type\":\"long\",\"value\":123}],\"meta_data\":{\"timestamp\":1474367139000,\"count\":{\"app1\":120}}}"; 

        Gson gsonv10 = new GsonBuilder().setVersion(1.0).create();
        Gson gsonv11 = new GsonBuilder().setVersion(1.1).create();


        System.out.println("Using v11 on v11 JSON ==>" + gsonv11.fromJson(version11Json, MetricRootObject.class));
        System.out.println("Using v10 on v10 JSON ==>" + gsonv10.fromJson(version10Json, MetricRootObject.class));


        System.out.println("Using v10 on v11 JSON ==>" + gsonv10.fromJson(version11Json, MetricRootObject.class));
        System.out.println("Using v11 on v10 JSON ==>" + gsonv11.fromJson(version10Json, MetricRootObject.class));


    }
```

**POJO Class:-**

```
public class MetricRootObject implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8304164167299285496L;

    @Until(1.1)
    private String name;

    @Until(1.1)
    private Long timestamp;

    @Until(1.1)
    private String type;

    @Since(1.1)
    private List<Metrics> metrics;

    @Since(1.1)
    @SerializedName("meta_data")
    private MetaData metaData;

    @Until(1.1)
    private Integer value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MetricRootObject [name=" + name + ", timestamp=" + timestamp + ", type=" + type + ", metrics=" + metrics
                + ", metaData=" + metaData + ", value=" + value + "]";
    } 


}

public class Metrics implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8304164167299285496L;

    @Since(1.1)
    private String name;

    @Since(1.1)
    private Long timestamp;

    @Since(1.1)
    private String type;

    @Since(1.1)
    private Integer value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Metrics [name=" + name + ", timestamp=" + timestamp + ", type=" + type + ", value=" + value + "]";
    } 


}

public class MetaData implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4332864980951634867L;

    @Since(1.1)
    private Long timestamp;

    @Since(1.1)
    @SerializedName("count")
    private MetricsCount count;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MetaData [timestamp=" + timestamp + ", count=" + count + "]";
    }
}
```